# Load .jasper in the service layer with spring 2.5

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I am developing a web application with maven, spring 2.5 and some other technologies.
The application it is composed of 3 layer dao service and web, the dao and service are packed as jar and used as libraries for my web application which is finally packed as a ear this is the final structure.

```
   myappp.ear 
       --mywebapp.war
         --lib
            --dao.jar
            --service.jar
```

Until now i have deployed the reports (.jasper) in the web layer defined in views.xml file. Now i am trying to move my reports to the service. The problems i have faced is that a can not load my reports. this a sample code

```
public class myreportingservice{
      private InputStream report;

      @autowired
      public void setReport(InputStream report){
            this.report = report;
      }
    //THE CODE THAT EJECUTES THE REPORT.

}
```

This is the xml that loas the config.

```
<beans xmlns .........

     <bean id="formatoTiempoEnProcesos" class="java.io.FileInputStream">
    <constructor-arg value="c:/evaluacionDeProveedores.jasper">     </constructor-arg>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

as you can see in the **constructor arg ** it is wrote the whole path and it woks fine, but if i want to use a relative path the bean can not be loaded, i have tried with this
"classpath:/reportes/evaluacionDeProveedores.jasper" and "/reportes/evaluacionDeProveedores.jasper" and many ways but unt now i just get errors.

Hope some one can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`classpath:/relative/path` should be resolved to a `Resource`, so change your bean field from `InputStream` to `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`. You can then call `.getInputStream()` on the resource

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine. for those peaple interested this was the final config.

Comment: <bean id="resource" class="org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource">
     <constructor-arg value="classpath:/reportes/evaluacionDeProveedores.jasper"></constructor-arg>
 </bean>